# Logic Issue when comparing lines to user names

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am dumping output from an ASA for anyconnect. I am writing that to a file then reading it back into the program. I am opening a csv of usernames from the day before to try to discover if anyone new connected. The issue is in my logic. I cant figure out how to compare each user(line) in the csv file to every line from the output and if none of them are in the line then print the line. My code will find a user not in the line but print the line when the line contains a user in my list. For example, I have usrA and usrB, if usrA is not in the line but usrB is in the line it will print it even though I have usrB in my list.

```
def compare(e):
    with open("anyconnect.csv", 'r') as usrf:
        for user in usrf:
            if user not in line:
                print(line)



def asa1(asaip0):
    device = {
        'device_type': 'cisco_asa',
        'ip': asaip0,
        'username': ("username"),
        'password': ("password"),
        'secret': ("password"),
        'port': 22,
        }

    with open(asaip0 + ".txt", 'w') as of:
        with open("log.csv", 'w') as log:
            net_connect = netmiko.ConnectHandler(**device)
            output = net_connect.send_command("show logging | grep LOCAL")
            of.writelines(output)
            log.writelines(output)
            log.close()

        with open("log.csv", 'r') as log:
            for line in log:
                compare(line)

###### MAIN ######
if __name__ == "__main__":

    asa1 = ('10.210.92.4')
    asa2 = ('10.210.109.4')
    ips = (asa1, asa2)
    asa1(asa1)
    asa1(asa2)
```

Comment: I like how someone voted down but does not say anything.

Comment: Probably something like `if not any(user in line for user in usrf)` instead of your first for loop + if.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*You have some weird things going on with variable names, so this is written with some assumptions*)

One option would be to change this to something like:

```
def compare(line):
    with open("anyconnect.csv", 'r') as usrf:
        user_found = False
        for user in usrf:
            if user in line:
                user_found = True
                break        # Not necessary, but will speed things up

        if not user_found:
            print(line)
```

Here, we're only concerned whether `line` (the argument) is in ***any*** of the `user` lines (from the anyconnect file).

There's definitely a better way than opening and looping through all the loops for each `compare(e)` call (like reading it once, extracting the known usernames, creating a set, and using `e in your_set`), but this should get you started.

Even something like:

```
with open("anyconnect.csv", 'r') as usrf:
    ANYCONNECT = [line for line in usrf]

def is_known(name):
    return any(name in line for line in ANYCONNECT)
```

Would be more efficient

Comment: OP would probably want to refactor the code to avoid loading `usrf` separately for each line.

Comment: @trailing_whitespace I agree, I think parsing the names out of the anyconnect file (read once) and making a set would probably be best, but I added an intermediary option at the bottom of my answer (since I can't go all the way with the name parsing, not knowing the format of anyconnect.csv